# How to modify my code to set sum/avg to negative if any one value is negative

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Below is my existing SQL code (sql server) that didn't check for error values.  It simply calculates a sum column and an average column if the month and year values match.

```
SELECT ur.Domain, SUM(ur.DataUsageInBytes) as SumDataUsageInBytes, 
       AVG(ur.DiskUsageInBytes) as AvgDiskUsageInBytes
FROM UsageResults ur
WHERE (ur.Year = @year) AND (ur.Month = @month) 
GROUP BY [Domain]
```

I want to add logic such that if any ur.DataUsageInBytes value(for the given month/year) is negative I want to set the sum to say -99, otherwise I'll just compute the normal sum.  The same goes for the average.

The table entries it is reading will have negative values if there was an error encountered and their values couldn't be determined.

Comment: How could `DataUsageInBytes` ever be negative? Surely it can only be 0 or more? Same goes for disk usage?

Comment: @Oded Op says on the question that those columns will have negative number if there was an error and the real values couldn't be determined

Comment: `case when Min( ur.DataUsageInBytes ) < 0 then -99 else Sum( ur.DataUsageInBytes ) end`?

Comment: I have a powershell script that writes negative values to the table if it was unable to determine them.  Permisssion issues for one.  Or if the IIS log file didn't include cs-bytes and/or sc-bytes, in which case I couldn't determine the amount of data transferred for that entry.

Comment: @HABO you should post that as an answer

Comment: TY HABO for your answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  ur.Domain
,       case 
        when min(ur.DataUsageInBytes) < 0 then -99
        else sum(ur.DataUsageInBytes) 
        end as SumDataUsageInBytes
,       case 
        when min(ur.DataUsageInBytes) < 0 then -99
        else avg(ur.DataUsageInBytes) 
        end as AvgDiskUsageInBytes
FROM    UsageResults ur
WHERE   ur.Year = @year AND ur.Month = @month
GROUP BY 
        ur.Domain
```

Answer (score 0):

you could turn each value into a positive and compare sums

```
SELECT ur.Domain
, CASE WHEN SUM(ur.DataUsageInBytes) = SUM(ABS(ur.DataUsageInBytes)) THEN SUM(ur.DataUsageInBytes) ELSE -99 END as SumDataUsageInBytes
, CASE WHEN min(ur.DiskUsageInByters) < 0 THEN -99 ELSE AVG(ur.DiskUsageInBytes) END AS AvgDiskUsageInBytes
FROM UsageResults ur
WHERE (ur.Year = @year) AND (ur.Month = @month) 
GROUP BY [Domain]
```

Comment: @FrodoFraggins using min is probably faster, but not sure if the difference would be noticeable